# Bootstrap column breaks when the image has larger names

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row, which has class `col-sm-2` for six times.

I have got images in each `col-sm-2`, After I add images to all of the classes, the 7 image goes to the next line.

But when I have the name of the images large, It is breaking for some reason.

Please check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/surajshukla/580omscs/5/). Press f11 to see expanded view in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

you are closing bad the div tag in the "Regular Classic Button Down C02-B" image.

I recommend to you to put images to 100% of the container width, and it shrinks automatically.

Fix it and it works.

Comment: oops my bad, I failed to compiled the proper question.

here's the condition. These images are radio buttons and when I click them, I apply `1px solid border` and then it breaks

Comment: The problem is that I said to you. You are bad closing a div tag. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/580omscs/7

Comment: Still this answer should work. Use img-responsive on the images

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.col-sm-2 {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

let me know if it is worked

Comment: but I want the text to come in the next line instead of being in the same line, this will put the texts one on each other

Comment: Then what is your problem..? your question is something like " It is breaking for some reason". so I thought you don't need line breaking

Answer (score 0):

Please use width with 100% and your div tag is broken i have fixed both

```
img{
width:100%;
}
```

check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharD/pv20s0h3/) Thanks

so let me know in case you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I got the problem.

ok check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/scLnsynn/

i just removed `display:block` from your `input:checked + img` style

Check and let me know if it is worked

Comment: Nope it is not working, just drag the output section on the left and you'll see it breaking